# Export column range to text file from different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a macro to copy the data from the range of A1 to the last cell with data in column A in my second worksheet. This code will output the file to the same destination as the excel workbook, but the file is empty and I'm unsure why. It is currently exporting as a .txt, and I want it as a .prox, but I'm not sure if changing the output name to "ExportedData.prox" will affect the data

```
Sub OpenTextFile()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CellData As String
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim WS1 As Worksheet


Set WS1 = Worksheets(1)
Set WS2 = Worksheets(2)

WS2.Activate

FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ExportedData.txt"
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Open FilePath For Output As #1
For i = 1 To LastRow
CellData = ActiveCell(i).Value
Print #1, CellData
Next i
Close #1

WS1.Activate

MsgBox "Done", vbMsgBoxSetForeground

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
Sub OpenTextFile()

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CellData As String
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet


    Set WS1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set WS2 = Worksheets(2)

    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ExportedData.prox"
    LastRow = WS2.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        CellData = WS2.Cells(i, 1).Value '<< assumes ColA is being exported
        Print #1, CellData
    Next i
    Close #1

    WS1.Activate

    MsgBox "Done", vbMsgBoxSetForeground

End Sub
```